# UIPickerView reloading not working

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have a picker view with two components and five rows in each component.

In the first component I have five makes of cars: Toyota, Ford, Honda etc...  In the second component I have five models of the associated makes.

When you change the make the models should update with it.

The problem I have is that I cant seem to get component 2 to update according to 1.

The following is a snapshot of the code and what I have so far on the sim.

```
var keyArray: [String] = ["Nissan","Honda","Toyota","Ferrari","Bentley"]
var makeIndex = 0
var carDict : [String :[String]] = ["Nissan" : ["Sentra","Xterra","Versa","Altima","Maxima"], "Honda": ["Accord","Civic","Odyssey","Civic SE", "Accord LE"],"Toyota":["Corolla","Camry","4 Runner","Corolla LE","Camry SE"],"Ferrari": ["La Ferrari", "Modena", "Testarrosa","360 Spyder", "California"], "Bentley": ["Arnage","Continental","Flying Spur","Continental GT"]]

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 2

}
@IBOutlet weak var pickerLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var speedLabel: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    speedLabel.text = String(vehicleInst.speed)
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {

    switch component {

    case 0:

        if component == 0 {

            pickerView.reloadComponent(1)
            return keyArray[row]
        }
        return keyArray[row];



    case 1:


        var modelarray = carDict[keyArray[makeIndex]]

return modelarray![row];

    default:

        return "nothing";
    }



}
```

Comment: Please add the code that have issues

Comment: Thanks didnt even realize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update component 1 when the user has selected a make from component 0.
Implement `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` and then update your `makeIndex` there:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if component == 0 {
        makeIndex = row
        pickerView.reloadComponent(1)
    }
}
```

Here are the corresponding changes to `pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:`

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {

    switch component {

    case 0:

        return keyArray[row]

    case 1:

        var modelarray = carDict[keyArray[makeIndex]]

        return modelarray![row]

    default:

        return "nothing"
    }
}
```

By the way, you only have 4 Bentley models which causes a crash since you claim you have 5.